# Concentration bound for weakly dependent random variables

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, real-analysis

Hi,

Suppose we observe a sequence $R_1, ..., R_T$ of iid. random variables that equal $0$ with probability $p$ and with probability $1-p$ are sampled from a distribution with expected value $E(R) > 0$.

Given $t \leq T$, let $X_t$ denote the mean of the $R_1, ..., R_t$ that were sampled from the distribution. What can we say about the convergence of $\sum_{t=1}^T X_t$ around its mean $T E(R)$?

I would like to obtain some kind of Chernoff-Heoffding bound, but the variables $X_t$ are not independent. However, $|X_t - X_{t-1}| < O(1/S(t))$, where $s(t)$ is the number of random variables that were sampled from the distribution at time $t$. Also, note that a variable $X_t$  is independent of $X_{t-2},...,X_1$ given $X_{t-1}$.

Are there any tools out there that can be used for this problem?

Also, if the above problem can be solved, I would like to obtain an analogous bound on $\sum_{t=1}^T 1/(X_t)^2$ (assuming that $P(X_t = 0) = 0$).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The parameter $p$ seems completely redundant in your current setting. Also, do you assume a bound on the $R_i$? In any case, try searching for "Azuma's inequality" and "concentration of measure".

Comment: It's not clear to me that $p$ is redundant, because if an $R_t$ is not "activated" with probability $p$, then it is not counted in $X_t$. Also, I don't see how Azuma's inequality would apply, because the $X_t$ are not a martingale (as far as I can tell).

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. Can you give precise definition of $X_t$? is it $R_1+,\ldots,+R_t$ divided by the number of nonzeros among them?

Comment: @Ori: Why can't it be $(R_1+\cdots+R_t)/t$ as Volodymyr says?

Comment: @Brendan: Volodymyr wrote "if an $R_t$ is not "activated" with probability $p$, then it is not counted in $X_t$". I take this to mean that you divide by the number of activated $R_t$'s. This is also consistent with the expectation being $T E(R)$.

Comment: By what do you divide if the number of nonzero $R_i$ is $0$? In particular, if $R_1=0$, then what is $X_1$?

Comment: @Ori: Yes, I didn't see Volodymyr's comment. The question is confusingly written.

Comment: Volodymyr, is $R$ bounded?  Otherwise, where does your bound on $|X_t-X_{t-1}|$ come from?  Also, are $s(t)$ and $S(t)$ the same?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. Let me try to give a more formal definition: suppose the data is a sequence of tuples $(R_1, Y_1), (R_2, Y_2),...,(R_T, Y_T)$, with $Y_t \sim Ber(p)$ (this determines if an $R_t$ is "activated") and the $R_t$ are iid in $[0,1]$ with expectation $E(R)$ (so yes, @Brendan, the $R_t$ are bounded, I should have mentioned that). Let $S(t) = \sum_{i \leq t} Y_i$ and let $X_t = (\sum_{i \leq t : Y_i = 1} R_t) / S(t)$. So I have a sequence of means $X_t$, each with expectation $E(R)$, hence the expectation of the sum is $TE(R)$.

Comment: And the O(1/S(t)) bound follows immediately from the above definition.

Comment: Also, the $s(t)$ is a mistake, it should be $S(t)$.

Comment: @Douglas: I should have given this more thought, but for now I think we can just define $X_t$ to be 0 when $S(t) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{t=1}^T X_t$ is the sum of $t$ independent random variables, for example $\sum_{t=1}^4 X_t = \frac{25}{12}R_1 + \frac{13}{12}R_2 + \frac{7}{12}R_3 + \frac{1}{4}R_4$.  To get a Hoeffding-type tail estimate you might need information about the tails of $R$. Similarly for a Berry-Esseen bound. I don't understand your comment about $s(t)$ and $S(t)$ at all.

**With the OP's clarifications of the question (above), this answer is obsolete so please discard it.**

Comment: I don't understand your comment very well, but that's probably because my question wasn't clear in the first place. I hope my comments above made it more clear...